# Calculating Values for Reimann zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am trying to find values for $z$ in $\zeta(z)$. However I am tired of using the series:

$$\zeta(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^z}$$

Is there any other method to find $\zeta(z)$ for $Re(z)>1$?

Comment: Yes, there are many alternative representations of $\zeta$.  One of the easiest to obtain directly from the "standard" series representation is the relationship to the $\eta$ function.  And the standard series representation of $\eta$ is valid for $\text{Re}(z)>0$!

Comment: What do you mean by  "find $z$ in $\zeta(z)?$"  Do you want to compute the functional inverse $\zeta^{-1}(z)$  or just $\zeta(z)$ for  $z>1?$